# how to raise user defined exception in PL/SQLwhen duplicate row is inserted into the table.?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to create a user defined exception for duplicate row insertion i.e an excption is raised when a duplicate data(already present in the table) is inserted into the table.My table is dept with columns deptno,dname,loc.So, i want to raise user defined exception for duplicate entry.

```
    create or replace procedure ADD_DEPT(DEPTNO  in dept.deptno%type,
DNAME in dept.dname%type,LOC in dept.loc%type) is
    begin
    insert into dept values(DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC);
    end;
```

Comment: Une a unique constraint.  That is what they are for.

Comment: i know but i want to raise an user defined exception.

Comment: What is the criteria for "Duplicate Record" ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a unique constraint on `deptno`, or a primary key, as you should be, then you can raise a particular exception using `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` and `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`

```
create or replace procedure ADD_DEPT(DEPTNO  in dept.deptno%type,
DNAME in dept.dname%type,LOC in dept.loc%type) 
is
begin

  insert into dept values(DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC);

exception 

  when dup_val_on_index 
  then 
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Value duplicated on deptno' );

end;
```

**UPDATE**

Let me show you an example.

```
SQL> create table x ( c1 number not null primary key , c2 number ) ;

insert into x values ( 1 , '1' );

insert into x values ( 2 , '1' );

Table created.

SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL> create or replace procedure add_to_x ( p_c1 in number , p_c2 in number )
  2  is
begin
  3    4  insert into x values (p_c1 , p_c2);
commit;
  5    6  exception when dup_val_on_index
then
  7    8      raise_application_error(-20001,'Value duplicated on deptno' );
when others then
  9   10      raise;
end; 11
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> select * from x ;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          1

SQL> exec add_to_x ( 1 , 3 ) ;
BEGIN add_to_x ( 1 , 3 ) ; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Value duplicated on deptno
ORA-06512: at "SYS.ADD_TO_X", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Comment: dup_val_on_index is a system defined exception not user defined exception.

Comment: dup_val_on_index is a predefined exception to handle duplicates in tables that contains unique values. I guess that when you say `user defined exception` you meant to reinvent the wheel. Why to do something like Oracle is doing for you ?

Comment: actually, it's a exercise question for practice.

Comment: I guess, because it did not make any sense. Unless, you already know something that you should not do. User defined exceptions are for controlling parts of a program that respond to specific business requirements, and NEVER for replacing what Oracle already does.

Comment: yes, I understand but they want us to practice some user defined question so they have given us some questions.

Comment: `when others then raise;` doesn't do anything useful, and it obscures the original line number.

Comment: *"they want us to practice some user defined question so they have given us some questions"* It really is depressing how much time is wasted getting students to write programs which would absolutely be rejected in a real life code review.

Comment: @APC I couldn't have said it better myself

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for something like this.

```
create or replace procedure ADD_DEPT(P_DEPTNO  in dept.deptno%type,
P_DNAME in dept.dname%type,P_LOC in dept.loc%type) is
    duplicate_value_Exists EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA exception_init( duplicate_value_Exists, -20001 );
    v_count number;
    begin
    
        select count(1) 
        into v_count
        from dept 
        WHERE DEPTNO = P_DEPTNO 
        AND P_DNAME = DNAME 
        AND LOC = P_LOC;
        
        if v_count >= 1 then
            RAISE duplicate_value_Exists;
        else
            insert into dept values(P_DEPTNO,P_DNAME,P_LOC);
        end if;
    end;
```

Comment: you would agree with me that your solution is not offering any security that the counter will be 0. Why we want to count the values of a table to be sure that there are no duplicates, That is what constrains are for. So what happens if at almost the same time two processes are executing the same procedure ? your select count will say 0 , however at almost the same time another session has inserted the record. As you are not defining any transaction isolation level, by default is READ UNCOMMITED, therefore the second process will try to insert anyway.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I agree with you  and thats why contraint are there but requirement(probably this is some exercise question) of the user is do it using user defined exception

Comment: by the way the counter cannot be greater than 1. is either 0 or 1.

Comment: It can be greater than in case data is inserted directly without any constraint and not via this procedure, so just to be sure I have added >= condition

Comment: well, if the table has no constraint, and anyone ( except the procedure ) can insert in the table, then we are in Oz world and anything can happen.  In a normal world, even with this useless user defined exception, the table will have a constraint, therefore I stand. it could either 0 or 1 and nothing else.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez - "then we are in Oz world and anything can happen"* Clearly we are in Oz, or at least in that land where teachers set their students pointless coding exercises. So why make assumptions about the student's schema which aren't supported by anything the Seeker has included in their question?

Comment: @APC you can't be more right. I was amaze about the stupidity of the exercise, what is the point actually ? The teacher is proposing useless exercises that not only have nothing to do with the real world, but also imprint bad practices in people who is stating to learn.  the worse is that this is happening a lot ;)

Comment: @APC, and you know the worse. That actually the student upvote and accept the answer that provides the worse possible solution.  Someone will look for a similar question in the future , and he will find this question and perhaps he will trust that the accepted answer is the right one.